# How to fetch URL from google chrome to my android application using kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome, kotlin, url, fetch

How to **fetch URL** from google chrome to my Android Application, whenever user opens URL in chrome it should be fetched into my android application using **Kotlin**.
Basically I want to design firewall system in android device. By fetching URL I would like to compare it with my stored URL's. if it is matched then website will be blocked else user can enjoy it.